# Widen interaction area of cytoscape.js edge without increasing visual width

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to widen the interactive area of an edge in cityscape.js, without also increasing the drawn width?

E.g. is it possible to have an edge with a visual width of 2px, that will respond to any clicks in an area 10px on either side?

Comment: The library already does this automatically

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @maxkfranz and your excellent library. I wanted to know if there was a way to increase the clickable area beyond the default, similar to `overlay-padding`? But I've found an alternative approach that works for my use-case if not.

Comment: There are negative side effects of increasing those kinds of values too much.  They're already at the practical maximum (~8px, maybe?) IIRC.